# Capture quoted string in comma separated string using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match all the string withing double quotes which is separated by comma 
For eg in the sample string

```
"COUNT","count(1)","crmuser.accounts"
```

i want to match

```
COUNT
count(1)
crmuser.accounts
```

Regular expression `(?<=").*?(?=")` is matching the comma seperator as well which is not required. How can i exclude commas in the string.

Comment: Can there be a comma between the double quotes?

Comment: yes comma can be there within double quotes

Comment: You might use a capturing group instead of the lookarounds `"(.*?)"` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uzzGVF/1) Because the assertions do not consume a character they are also valid for `","` matching the comma.

Comment: But `"(.*?)"` will include `"` in the match, which i don't require. I just need the string inside the double quotes.

Comment: It will match it, but your value is in the capturing group (which has the green colour) https://regex101.com/r/uzzGVF/1

Comment: `...is matching the comma seperator as well` no it isn't. It doesn't match those commas.

Comment: Or  use `"([^"]+)"` to capture in a group matching not a double quote.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different workarounds you could use for this; for example using capture groups as suggested in the comments by The fourth bird. But for me personally, I try to avoid using `.*`.

For *this* type of example, I would honestly recommend just using a character set of valid characters you will use and looking for more than one character (2 or more) because you will effectively skip lone separators such as a single `,`. You can even add a comma to that character set and it will still work.

```
(?<=")[\w\(\)\.,]{2,}(?=")
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1SNVYR/1)

Comment: You don't have to escape the the parenthesis and the dot in the character class.  `\w` also matches `\d` so I think you could write it as `[\w().]` As the OP mentioned there could also be a comma present, you could also use `[\w().,]`

Comment: @Thefourthbird You don't have to, but I'm not positive of what is and isn't accepted in all Regex parsers so I put them in to be safe. And yes, I mentioned the comma part already.

Answer (score 0):

For this format of string you could just use :

```
var str = '"COUNT","count(1)","crmuser.accounts"' ;
var separated = str.split('","') ;
for(var i in separated){
     i.replace('"','') ;
} ;
```

Comment: I wanted a regular expression for the same, not a program. Thanks for the reply anyways.